# Is there any way to recover a OneNote file from Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: onenote, windows-mobile

I'm using OneNote on my Lumia 950 on Windows 10 Mobile. I recently had problems with getting one particular page to sync with OneDrive (not too much of a problem as it was still on my phone).

When I started OneNote on my phone today, it crashed when I clicked on the hamburger icon for the menu. During next app startup OneNote asked me, whether I wanted the settings to be reset which I accidentally confirmed.

Now my page in OneNote mentioned above is missing almost all of the information I entered over the last couple of months.

Now my question: Is there any way to recover it? As I said above, the page was never synced correctly to OneDrive, so if there is any way it has to be using my phone.

To begin with, I don't even now where the files are stored - on the SD card I couldn't find any (OneNote related) files using different recovery tools. I suspect that the information is still available on my phone but I cannot access it. Windows 10 Mobile only exposes certain folders and probably not a temporary / special folder where I still might find a version of my page containing all the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since OneNote files saved offline and hidden and cannot be read or edited by simply using a File Explorer, so you need to gain special permissions.

If you think the file is in your phone memory, first try switching to `Mass Storage Mode` via WPinternals, or turn on `Full File System Access` via Interop tools while you have connected the smartphone to a computer. Go to the directory where you can now see all system files of your phone and now start a search. If you remember the name of your OneNote file search for it. Instead turn off `Hide extensions for known file types` from Folder options in settings and then again search just by typing `.one` (That's the extension used by OneNote files.

Didn't find it there? Maybe it's on your SD card. Hook it up to an SD card reader and connect it to a computer. Search again in the same way.

If you still can't find it use a `file recovery tool` and search again on both your phone memory and SD card. You must be able to find it this time. If you can find it, do share the directory where these files are saved in the phone. (I actually haven't tried this yet)

Helped? Please give me an upvote! Still have a query? Ask me in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: I've marked your answer as correct as it describes what needs to be done, although not in enough detail for a Lumia 950 which seems to require additional steps.

Comment: I have managed to search through all the files in my Lumia Windows 10 phone, with the help of WPinternals, but I cannot find any .one files. Does anyone knows the directory where the OneNotes files are saved ?